# How do x86_64-pc-linux-gnu and x86_64-elf toolchain's targets relate?

Tags: linux, gcc, x86-64, cross-compiling

My `gcc` has `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` as a target (from `gcc -v`). So it can compile ELF binaries for `linux-gnu` environment (i.e., Linux+GLibc ?) for `x86_64` architecture.

[OSDev.org](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) says:

> This compiler that we build here will have a generic target (`x86_64-elf`) what allows you to leave the current operating system behind, meaning that no headers or libraries of your host operating system will be used.

So we need `x86_64-elf` compiler to build a bare metal. As I understand, it is a toolchain which can compile ELF binaries for an empty environment (i.e. without headers, operating system, libraries, etc.) for `x86_64` architecture.

By other side I can compile Linux kernel with a standard (`x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`) compiler.

1. Is GCC's target `x86_64-elf` a subset of `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`?
2. If yes, why does [OSDev.org](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) say to build an `x86_64-elf` toolchain?
3. If no, how do we compile Linux kernel with `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`?
4. How do targets really relate?

---

Comment: You can use a native Linux compiler (`x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`) for osdev stuff.  I'm not sure exactly what the difference is from `x86_64-elf`, but the important thing is that it's not targeting MinGW or anything, where it would add extra code in `main` and make non-ELF object files.  Perhaps the situation's similar to ARM cross-compilers, where you can have `arm-none-eabi-g++` vs. `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf-g++` as on https://godbolt.org/.  I've never been clear on that distinction, but I'd assumed it was like targeting bare-metal vs. targeting Linux user-space.